# Flutter : How can I change background color of CupertinoActionSheet?

Tags: flutter, background-color, flutter-cupertino, actionsheet

How can I change `CupertinoActionSheet` background color in flutter? I tried many possible ways. But its default color didn't change. how can I ?

**Sample Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:service/services/page_navigation_service.dart';
import 'package:service/view/variables/colors_variable.dart';
import 'package:service/view/variables/text_style.dart';

class MyCupertinoBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final String? title;

  const MyCupertinoBottomSheet({Key? key, required this.child, this.title})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoActionSheet(
      title: Text(
        title ?? "",
        style: CustomTextStyle.titleBoldStyleDarkGrey,
      ),
      message: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: CustomColors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: child,
      ),
      actions: [
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          onPressed: () {
            PageNavigationService.backScreen();
          },
          child: const Text('CONFIRM',
              style: CustomTextStyle.mediumBoldStylePrimary),
        ),
        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          onPressed: () {
            PageNavigationService.backScreen();
          },
          child: const Text(
            'CLOSE',
            style: CustomTextStyle.mediumBoldStyleDarkGrey,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I also used `Material`, `CupertinoTheme`. But those don't effect on it.

[image]

Comment: have u tried it with themedata?

Comment: @Kyrill yes, I tried

Comment: Please add your sample code

Comment: It depends on how are using, consider including [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RohanJariwala I added sample code

Comment: @AbirAhsan answer added